# postsharp build issue with log4net after upgrade to 4.3.16

Tags: log4net, postsharp

I was using the express version of 4.1.29 and it works fine. 
But when I upgrade to 4.3.16, I got the error. I have log4net 2.0.5 installed and I don't even find that I have log4net 1.2.15 in my machine. 
Does postsharp 4.3.16 has a hard dependency on log4net 1.2.15?

```
Unhandled exception (4.3.16.0, postsharp-net40-x86-srv.exe, CLR 4.0.30319.394254, Release): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyLoadException: Cannot find assembly 'log4net, version=1.2.15.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a'. [Version mismatch]
```

I checked my solution/project.
1. All project's log4net is upgraded to 2.0.5 using nuget.
2.All my project config file will redirect log4net to 2.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4net 1.2.15 is the log4net version where 2.0.5 is the nuget version. It seems you do not need to redirect the logging when you are using the latest version of postsharp:

[nuget postsharp diagnostics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.Log4Net/)

[nuget log4net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/)

Comment: This is correct. If you are still experiencing the issue, try to create a new project, add logging using PostSharp UI (using the smart tag on a method is the most straightforward way) and try to check for differences between the new project and yours.